How to manage media files efficiently in flutter
I am creating a flutter app in which I am showing images and videos from the phone's storage in Gridview on separate screens. The photos and videos can be in thousands. The image screen works smoothly with a small number of images 100-200 but when it goes to thousands, the app starts lagging and pictures don't load correctly. Same with the videos tab. Video thumbnail generation takes lots of time and resources for the first time which makes the app laggy and sometimes the phone starts overheating. I am using provider state management. I have seen a lot of similar apps and they are working perfectly with thousands of videos and photos. I also tried loading only 20-30 images and videos at the start that are visible on the screen and then loading more once the user scrolls down but still performance issues. I am using the video_thumbnail package for generating thumbnails. My question is how I can manage my app to run smoothly with thousands of images and videos.

Maybe you can give uniqe value key each listview element this will increese optimization

how do you create those video thumbnails? by calling native, system's createVideoThumbnail method?

I am creating video thumbnails by using video_thumbnail package

it seems that video_thumbnail creates thumbnails not effectively - you should find (or write) a package that uses createVideoThumbnail (or similar native call)

Make sure that previous images are clear from the memory and new ones will load. If previous images are in memory it will lead to memory leak.

what do you mean by previous images? the images that user scroll up or images that are not present now
